# Some recessions not showing up on plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am using yearly data from FRED to plot the percent change in GDP from the preceding period. However, when I try to use the USRec from FRED, the smaller recessions (ones lasting less than a year) do not show up. I believe this is because my data is yearly and the recessions are monthly, but is there a way to get around this issue?

```
rGDP = getSymbols('A191RL1Q225SBEA',src='FRED',auto.assign=FALSE)
rate = subset(rGDP, index(rGDP)>="1960-01-01")
rate2 <- ts(rate, start=c(1960,1), frequency=4)
yearly <- aggregate(rate2, nfrequency=1, mean)
```

Recession code:

```
rec <- getSymbols("USREC",src="FRED",auto.assign=FALSE)
start <- index(rec[which(diff(rec$USREC)==1)])
end   <- index(rec[which(diff(rec$USREC)==-1)-1])
cycles.dates <- paste(format(start,"%Y-%m"),format(end[-1],"%Y-%m"),sep="/")
```

chart.TimeSeries code:

```
chart.TimeSeries(rate,
    period.areas=cycles.dates, 
    period.color="lightblue", 
    lwd=1,
    xlab="",
    ylab="",
    main="",
    minor.ticks=FALSE,
    las=1)
```

Which gives me this:

[Time Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibRtS.png)

Comment: Nothing you can do other than get more granular data. See here: https://github.com/Quartz/bad-data-guide/blob/master/README.md#data-are-too-coarse